# Prevent newline in div

Tags: html

If I were to have a div with a specified width, how would I prevent a new line when the content exceeds the parent div's width?
Here is my HTML code:

`<div style="width: 200"><p>Verrrrrrry loooooooong pppppppp ellllemmmmmmmmentttt</p></div>`

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not certain, but maybe try this: `<div style="width: 200; overflow: hidden;"><p>Verrrrrrry loooooooong pppppppp ellllemmmmmmmmentttt</p></div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use:

```
div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; /* assuming you don't want the <div> to stretch to accommodate */
}                     /* the width of the text */
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>This element has some text longer, by far, than the width of the page in which it is contained; it would be lorem ipsum but, honestly, I'd rather spend a few moments typing randomly, but continuously, than go find myself some of that lorem-goodness...</div>
```

References:

- [`white-space` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).
- [`white-space` (W3.org, CSS 2.1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

```
div{
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevent text from overflowing div */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text from using more than one line */
}
```

Comment: In the documentation *you link to* it shows there is no `-` in the property value. Though I made the same mistake in my own first draft, which is somewhat interesting.

Comment: @DavidThomas I recalled it wrong myself, as well. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```

Should do the trick